# Need help understanding Godel's incompleteness Theorem Proof

Tags: incompleteness

So I've been trying to understand this theorem for the past week and there is a proof (Not rigorous) that was given to me that I just cannot understand. I'm not gonna lie I'm not so good at mathematics but, I've read it like 50 times+ and it just doesn't make sense to me.

Can anyone for the love of god help dumb this down step by step? I'm genuinely so lost... I understand godel numbers and the general structure of how it's made.

Here's the proof:

We begin with the observation that we can substitute the Godel Number of a formula into itself. Consider the statement “The formula with Godel number sub(y, y, m) cannot be proved”, where our notation sub() means to substitute, our formula has y somewhere in it and we substitute variable y
anywhere y exists in the formula with the Godel Number of y that is denoted as m. This formula itself should have a Godel Number and we denote it as n.

Create new formula by substituting the number n everywhere for y in our previous formula, which now reads “The formula with Godel Number sub(n, n, 17) cannot be proved. Let’s call this formula G and has its own Godel Number. But by definition, sub(n, n, 17) is the Godel Number of the formula that results from taking the formula with Godel Number n and
substituting n anywhere there’s a symbol with Godel Number 17. Because of unique prime factorization, formula G is talking about itself. So G states that it can’t be proved itself, but if proven it would mean opposite of G,
which says no proof exists and thus G is undecidable. But G is true and yet undecidable That can be constructed from an axiomatic system, thus any system can be shown to be incomplete.

Comment: See also [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1493587/understanding-g%c3%b6dels-1931-paper-the-undecidability-theorem)

Comment: The proof works by establishing a self-referential statement that essentially says "I cannot be proven". If the statement is true, then it cannot be proven. If it is false, then... it cannot be proven. The rest is technicalities to formalize the statement.